# Transform a variadic pack of types into values?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I have some function

```
template<typename T>
constexpr Foo make_foo<T>();
```

which essentially maps types to instances of `Foo` with no side-effects.

Now, I want to write the function `magic`,

```
template<typename Types...>
vector<Foo> magic();
```

which does the same as make_foo, but for variadic parameter packs; and in a way which it would then be easy for me to, say, stream all these Foo's to std::cout, or to iterate over them in a loop etc. I realize this question is not entirely well-defined, since I'm not clear if the relevant output I'm looking for is somekind of variadic packs of values (seeing how that doesn't exist in runtime).

So, what's the idiomatic way of doing that? I noticed that Eric Niebler has a blog page about a [metaprogramming library](http://ericniebler.com/2014/11/13/tiny-metaprogramming-library/) which seems to be relevant, but it seems like a bit overkill. For my case.

Comment: You mean something like `auto foo_list = {make_foo<Types>()...};`?

Comment: It sounds like you really just want a `tuple<Types...>` and some helper classes?

Comment: @CollinDauphinee: No, I need to act on the _types_ not values of these types.

Comment: @T.C.: Umm, yes, sorry, I had an std::string (which is what my Foo actually is). So it could be a list of Foo's, or a vector of Foos etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a vector of `Foo`s, then it's just

```
template<typename Types...>
vector<Foo> magic(){
    return { make_foo<Types>()... };
}
```

You can also throw them into a local array and play with them however you want:

```
Foo foos[] = { make_foo<Types>()... };
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to access individual members of a parameter pack is via recursion, stripping off one or more members out of a time.  In this case, we could make `magic()` a wrapper function, that passes the parameter pack to a worker function that in turn calls `make_foo<T>()`.  So, assuming `make_foo<T>()` can only take a single type at a time, we would have something like this.

```
// Prototypes:
// -----
template<typename T>
constexpr Foo make_foo();

template<typename... Types>
std::vector<Foo> magic();

template<>
std::vector<Foo> magic<>();

template<typename T>
void magic_worker(std::vector<Foo>& vec);

template<typename T, typename U, typename... Types>
void magic_worker(std::vector<Foo>& vec);

// Actual code:
// -----
// The wrapper.
template<typename... Types>
std::vector<Foo> magic() {
    std::vector<Foo> vec;

    magic_worker<Types...>(vec);

    return vec;
}

// Empty parameter pack.
template<>
std::vector<Foo> magic<>() {
    return std::vector<Foo>(0);
}

// Only one type left.
template<typename T>
void magic_worker(std::vector<Foo>& vec) {
    vec.push_back(make_foo<T>());
}

// At least two types left.
template<typename T, typename U, typename... Types>
void magic_worker(std::vector<Foo>& vec) {
    vec.push_back(make_foo<T>());
    magic_worker<U, Types...>(vec);
}
```

Not sure if this is the most efficient way to do what you want, but it should work.  You can output the vector to `std::cout` via a range-based for loop, if you so desire.

```
std::vector<Foo> vec = magic</* args */>();

for (auto& a : vec) {
    std::cout << a;
}
```

For a working example, see [here](http://ideone.com/U9TSVT).

---

Edit: If you're wondering why the recursive version of `magic_worker()` has two distinct template parameters before the pack, it's to remove ambiguity.  As a template pack can have zero members, having one version take `<typename T>` and the other take `<typename T, typename... Types>` would confuse the compiler, and prevent your code from compiling.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433746/template-specialization-for-an-empty-parameter-pack) for more info.